# Resolution of the login screen is wrong on a second monitor

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

Is it possible to do changes to the login screen in Ubuntu 11.10? I'm running with a laptop and an external screen and in boot and login they're mirrored and has a weird resolution.

To clarify: I'm using my laptop with an external screen, with my laptop to the right and the screen in front of me. I've set it up as an extended desktop (is that right?). But it's not like that on the login screen, there, my screens are mirrored and has a weird resolution, way bigger than it should be. Does that make any sense?

When logged in, my external screen is the "main" window, where the top bar is and so on. To my left, my laptop has only the desktop wallpaper, there I can place whatever I like. It's like one big desktop on two screens. So, at login I would like the same.

Can I fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking about here? If it is two questions, please split them as such. I was going to edit your question make it make more sense but I'm a wee bit lost :P.

Comment: Sorry, he he. It's one question. I'm using my laptop with an external screen, with my laptop to the right and the screen in front of me. I've set it up as an extended desktop (is that right?). But it's not like that on the login screen, there, my screens are mirrored and has a weird resolution, way bigger than it should be. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Edit the question so you can easily see what's the problem, instead of reading comments. :)

Comment: I've done that and then Jorge Castro has apparently changed edited it too, should be good to go :)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want each screen to do while on the login screen?

Comment: When logged in, my external screen is the "main" window, where the top bar is and so on. To my left, my laptop has only the desktop wallpaper, there I can place whatever I like. It's like one big desktop on two screens. So, at login I would like the same.

I have updated my answer too.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'll upload a picture/YouTube of the problem and edt the post if that's Ok with tbleckert.

Comment: Of course, that would be great!

Comment: i think this happens with gdm or whatever instead of xorg.  i could be mistaken.  i would look at saving a custom xorg.conf though.

Comment: Do you need both screens for he login? If not just write a startup script with the **disper** command that automatically extends your displays when you log in and not before.

Comment: That sounds good...too bad I have no idea what a disper is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The login screen in 11.10 uses the default X behaviour for multi-monitors.  In most cases this is mirroring, but various drivers can behave incorrectly (e.g. incorrect resolutions or not working second monitors).  We have this in 11.10 as the original solution of managing the monitors like the session does had more problems.

This feature is planned to be revisited for 12.04 to make the experience better.  The desired behaviour is the monitors run at their native resolutions, have the background correctly scaled/cropped and a user can log in from any available monitor.

Comment: I'm on the 12.04 LTS and having shorter resolution on notebook's external monitor until login.