# Resolution in login screen

Tags: laptop, login, resolution, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resolution of the login screen is wrong on a second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71529/resolution-of-the-login-screen-is-wrong-on-a-second-monitor)

last weekend i tried to personalize my ubuntu a bit and i was able to destroy it until i was only able to boot a terminal only :( so i just reinstalled ubuntu.

before im doing such a **** again... i better ask for help :)

the Problem: I have 2 screens. One Screen of my Laptop, my Main Screen with a resultuion of 1600x900 and another screen, a simple flat screen with a simple resolution of 1280x1024.

For me it looks like my login screen has a resolution of 1280x1024 and is copied on both screens. But that looks bad on my laptop so i wish there was a ppossibility of either get the korrect resolution on each screen nor let the monitor black until the login has finished but with the correct resolution for the main screen.

Hopefully you understood what i meant....

regards
Timo

Comment: Just wound the answer myself... thats enough for me

http://askubuntu.com/questions/71529/resolution-of-the-login-screen-is-wrong-on-a-second-monitor